# how to pass DomDocument in & out of functions in vba

Tags: xml, excel, vba, domdocument

I have a VBA function that calls itself recursively to navigate all the branches of a directory tree in the usual manner.  In this function, if a file in the current directory  matches a certain criteria, that file is opened and data extracted.

I then want to write this data to an XML file.  As the XML file may or may not be updated (possibly several times) by each instance of the function, I pass the current XML file into the function, and after writing a new node the updated XML file needs to be passed back to the function instance that called it.

The relevant code is:
1) The sub that calls the function initializes the XML file (as a Document) then passes it to the function, thus:

```
Dim XMLSource As DOMDocument
Set XMLSource = New DOMDocument
FindDir = "mydirectory/path"
XMLSource = MyRecursiveFunction(FindDir, XMLSource)
```

2) The recursive function takes it in thus:

```
Private Function MyRecursiveFunction(ByVal FindDir As String, ByRef XMLSource As DOMDocument) As DOMDocument
```

3) it is called recursively thus:

```
For Each subfolder In ObjFolder.SubFolders
    XMLSource = MyRecursiveFunction(subfolder, XMLSource)
Next subfolder
```

4) and returns it's value:

```
MyRecursiveFunction = XMLSource
```

Whenever it gets to the 'exit function' it returns a 438 error.
I've commented out the part where it writes to the DOMDocument, so it's not a formatting problem, it's only passing the file in and out at this stage.
I used an existing recursive function that works fine with passing strings or integers in and out.
it definitely has the right libraries loaded etc as all my other XML programs work.

Any ideas?

whole code as requested:

```
Private Sub CatFiles()

Target = "my path here\"
 Dim XMLSource As DOMDocument
 Set XMLSource = New DOMDocument

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder1 = objFso.GetFolder(Target + "directory 1\")
    FindDir = Target + "directory 1\"
    XMLSource = RecursGet(FindDir, XMLSource)

Set Folder2 = objFso.GetFolder(Target + "directory 2")
    FindDir = Target + "directory 2\"
    XMLSource = RecursGet(FindDir, XMLSource)

    XMLSource.Save ("path here\Data.xml")
    MsgBox ("Consoldiation done")
End Sub

Private Function RecursGet(ByVal FindDir As String, ByRef XMLSource As DOMDocument) As DOMDocument

    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ObjFolder = objFso.GetFolder(FindDir)
    Dim Filename() As String

    For Each subfolder In ObjFolder.SubFolders
        XMLSource = RecursGet(subfolder, XMLSource)
    Next subfolder

    For Each Item In ObjFolder.Files
        ReDim Preserve Filename(itemNumber)
        Filename(itemNumber) = Item
        itemNumber = itemNumber + 1
    Next Item 

If Not IsArray(Filename) Then
    Exit Function
End If

On Error Resume Next
    itemNumber = UBound(Filename)
 If itemNumber > 0 Then
    For EI = 0 To itemNumber 
         If InStr(Filename(EI), ".xls") Then

            Dim RecordSet As IXMLDOMElement
            Dim RSAttrib As IXMLDOMAttribute
            Set RecordSet = XMLSource.createElement("RecordSet")
            XMLSource.appendChild (RecordSet)
            Workbooks.Open (Filename(EI))

            PathHold = Split(Filename(EI), "/")
            File = PathHold(UBound(PathHold))

            Set RSAttrib = XNLSource.createElement("RecordSet")
            RSAttrib.NodeValue = File
            RecordSet.setAttributeNode (RSAttrib)

            With ActiveSheet
                Set FoundAdd = Cells.Find(What:="Resource Title *", LookIn:=xlValues)
            End With 
             If FoundAdd = Null Then 
                MsgBox ("File " + File + " doesn't have a standard data layout, please fix")
                ResTitle = "please adjust file " + File
            Else
                FoundRange = "B" + FoundAdd.Row 
                ResTitle = Range(FoundRange).Value
            End If

            Dim D1 As IXMLDOMElement
            Set D1 = XMLSource.createElement("ResTitle")
            RSAttrib.appendChild D1
            D1.Text = ResTitle    

           ActiveWorkbook.Close

         End If
    Next EI
End If
  RecursGet = XMLSource

End Function
```

Comment: If you change `MyRecursiveFunction = XMLSource` to `Set MyRecursiveFunction = XMLSource`, is there any difference. It's hard to tell where the problem is, if we don't see the whole code or at least more.

Comment: no, unfortunately it didn't help.  here's the whole code (mostly):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I think is that a `DomDocument` is an object variable, and therefore you need to use the `Set` keyword when making an assignment statement.

```
For Each subfolder In ObjFolder.SubFolders
    Set XMLSource = MyRecursiveFunction(subfolder, XMLSource)
Next subfolder
```

As @MiVoth mentions, within the function, you will also need to:

```
Set RecursGet = XMLSource
```

Personally, I would change `RecursGet` to a subroutine, instead of a function, and pass the Dom object  `ByRef`.  Then you should be able to just:

```
For Each subfolder In ObjFolder.SubFolders
     MyRecursiveFunction subfolder, XMLSource
Next subfolder
```

You will be able to omit the `Set RecursGet = XMLSource` from the recursive sub.

Comment: Thank you, I went for the subroutine method.  For some reason (probably me getting it wrong) I had to add a node into the initial xml file and then write the data from the recursive subroutine using  XMLSource.FirstChild.appendChild RecordSet otherwise it only wrote the first record to the xml file